# How can I make pynput.mouse do a task N times?

Tags: python, loops, task, pynput

How can I make Python do this task

```
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller

mouse = Controller()
mouse.position(660,226)
mouse.press(Button.left)
mouse.release(Button.left)
```

every 10 seconds, X amount of times?

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the thing you want to do multiple times in a `for` block, for example like this:

```py
for iteration in range(X):
    # do the thing
```

Make sure to replace X by the amount of actions you want to do.

You can also add a `time.sleep(seconds)` to the end of the action inside the `for` block to make it sleep each time after completing the action.

Answer (score 0):

To make the task repeat, use a for loop. To do it every ten seconds, use the sleep function. Example:

```
from time import sleep
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller

x = 10 # The amount of times to repeat the task

def task():
    mouse = Controller()
    mouse.position(660,226)
    mouse.press(Button.left)
    mouse.release(Button.left)

for _ in range(x):
    task()
    sleep(10)
```